# Modify some rows of one column based on conditions from another column using Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Given the data frame below, I would need to modify column 'A' using conditions of 'B'. Pandas expression for that is presented with `.loc`

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
    "A": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'B': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
    }
)

df.loc[df['B'] == 2, 'A'] = 100
```

I have a big data set and I need to do this a lot of times for small samples. I know that it is possible to solve with `apply` function by going through all rows, but I need a fast solution, O(1) if possible, instead of O(n).
I tried to use

```
df[df['B'] == 2, 'A'] = 100
```

but it works only when one row met the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```py
In [9]: df.with_columns(A=pl.when(pl.col('B')==2).then(100).otherwise(pl.col('A')))
Out[9]:
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 100 ┆ 2   │
│ 100 ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘
```